# debugger not stopping incase [__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode

when I got [__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance, the debbuger not stop, only if global breakpoint mode is on.

Is there way to make the debugger stop/ "crash" when this happen even if the break mode is off ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add exception breakpoint (bottom of breakpoints tab):

[image: like that]

This way, the debugger will stop the program every time an exception is raised.

But it won't work if you turn off breakpoints

Comment: this is the situation I have right now. I thought maybe there is some setting that tell debugger stop even if breakpoint are off. 

I dont understand why the debugger/app not "crash" in this case.